# Sort a list using a scoring list with Switch

Tags: function-construction, sorting, pure-function

I have a minimal working example (MWE) list called `listToSort` that is a list of string triplets:

```
listToSort = {{"B", "X", "Y"}, {"C", "Y", "X"}, {"C", "X", "Y"}, {"A", "X", "Y"}};
```

I wish to sort `listToSort` by the first element in each triplet so that the triplets starting with `"C"` come *first*, the triplets starting with `"B"` come next, and the triplets starting with `"A"` come *last*. I would like the second and third elements to be sorted in canonical order (i.e., `"X"` comes before `"Y"`).

One way to do this is with [`SortBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html) and [`Which`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Which.html):

```
SortBy[listToSort, Which[#[[1]] == "C", 1, #[[1]] == "B", 2, #[[1]] == "A", 3] &]
```

> `{{"C", "X", "Y"}, {"C", "Y", "X"}, {"B", "X", "Y"}, {"A", "X", "Y"}}`

However, it is quite verbose and takes a lot of typing to use `Which` as above. [`Switch`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Switch.html), on the other hand, uses a more compact syntax and still gives the desired output:

```
SortBy[listToSort, Switch[#[[1]], "C", 1, "B", 2, "A", 3] &]
```

> `{{"C", "X", "Y"}, {"C", "Y", "X"}, {"B", "X", "Y"}, {"A", "X", "Y"}}`

But, what if I want to use `Switch` in tandem with a *list* of scoring values called `atomsScoreList`?

```
atomsScoreList = {{"C", 1}, {"B", 2}, {"A", 3}};
```

I notice that I can use [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) to obtain a `Switch` function analogous to the example above. For instance:

```
Apply[Switch["C", ##] &, Flatten[atomsScoreList]]
Apply[Switch["B", ##] &, Flatten[atomsScoreList]]
Apply[Switch["A", ##] &, Flatten[atomsScoreList]]
```

> `1` `2` `3`

**How do I incorporate a similar [`Switch`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Switch.html) function in a call to [`SortBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html)? In particular, could you please help me understand how I can use the slots ([`#`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) and [`##`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SlotSequence.html)) and `&` to specify the correct pure function(s)?**

For example, this attempt fails to yield the desired output:

```
SortBy[listToSort, Apply[Switch[#[[1]] &, ##] &, Flatten[atomsScoreList]]]
```

I probably have the `&`s in the wrong places. Could you please help me?

(By the way, I'm running a very old version of *Mathematica*: version 9. I would like potential solutions to work in version 9.)

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

listToSort = {{"B", "X", "Y"}, {"C", "Y", "X"}, {"C", "X", "Y"}, {"A",
     "X", "Y"}};

atomsScoreList = {{"C", 1}, {"B", 2}, {"A", 3}};

SortBy[listToSort, Position[SortBy[
      atomsScoreList, Last][[All, 1]], #[[1]]][[1, 1]] &]

(* {{"C", "X", "Y"}, {"C", "Y", "X"}, {"B", "X", "Y"}, {"A", "X", "Y"}} *)

SortBy[listToSort, Switch[#[[1]],
   Evaluate[Sequence @@ Flatten[atomsScoreList]]] &]

(* {{"C", "X", "Y"}, {"C", "Y", "X"}, {"B", "X", "Y"}, {"A", "X", "Y"}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's specify the order of the first elements in an easy way, just list the possible first elements in the order you want:

```
OrderingOfFirstElements = {"C", "B", "A"};
```

This turns out to be just reverse order, but I'm assuming that's coincidence and that you want a general strategy.

Now let's define an ordering function that uses that specification:

```
MyTripletOrder[a_, b_] := 
  If[
    a[[1]] == b[[1]],
    Order[Rest@a, Rest@b],
    Sign @@
      (FirstPosition[OrderingOfFirstElements, b[[1]]] - 
       FirstPosition[OrderingOfFirstElements, a[[1]]])]
```

Now we can supply this ordering function to Sort:

```
listToSort = {{"B", "X", "Y"}, {"C", "Y", "X"}, {"C", "X", "Y"}, {"A", "X", "Y"}};
Sort[listToSort, MyTripletOrder]
```

`{{"C", "X", "Y"}, {"C", "Y", "X"}, {"B", "X", "Y"}, {"A", "X", "Y"}}`

If your rule is actually just simply to reverse-sort on the first element (so the coincidence wasn't merely coincidental), you could simplify:

```
MyTripletOrder[a_, b_] :=
  If[
    a[[1]] == b[[1]],
    Order[Rest@a, Rest@b],
    Order[b[[1]], a[[1]]]]
```

Now, if you only ever have just these three starting elements (i.e. A, B, and C), then you could be more direct:

```
MyTripletOrder[{a_, as__}, {a_, bs__}] := Order[{as}, {bs}];
MyTripletOrder[{"C", _, _}, {_, _, _}] := 1;
MyTripletOrder[{"B", _, _}, {"A", _, _}] := 1;
MyTripletOrder[{"B", _, _}, {"C", _, _}] := -1;
MyTripletOrder[{"A", _, _}, {_, _, _}] := -1;
```

**NOTE**

It looks like FirstPosition was introduce in version 10. So, here's an alternate:

```
MyTripletOrder[a_, b_] :=
  If[
    a[[1]] == b[[1]],
    Order[Rest@a, Rest@b],
    Sign @@
      Flatten[
        Position[OrderingOfFirstElements, b[[1]]] - 
        Position[OrderingOfFirstElements, a[[1]]]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

In each sublist, leave the first letter unchanged but "invert" the remaining letters $(a \leftrightarrow z, b \leftrightarrow y, ...)$.  Then use a traditional sort... on the first element, then second element, then third...  Finally, re-"invert" all the characters except the first.

```
invertLetter[x_String] := FromLetterNumber[27 - LetterNumber[x]];

ToUpperCase /@ Flatten[{First[#], invertLetter /@ Rest[#]}] & /@ 
 ReverseSortBy[(Flatten[{First[#], invertLetter /@ Rest[#]}] & /@ 
    listToSort), First]
```

(*

{{"C", "X", "Y"}, {"C", "Y", "X"}, {"B", "X", "Y"}, {"A", "X", "Y"}}

*)